# Nesting flat XML siblings

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

Attemping to transform XML with XSLT 2.0.

Flat Source XML:

```
<body>
  <R1/>
  <R1/>
  <R2/>
  <R2/>
  <R2/>
  <R3/>
  <R3/>
  <R3/>
  <R1/>
  <R1/>
  <R2/>
  <R2/>
  <R1/>
</body>
```

Desired Output:

```
<body>
  <R1/>
  <R1>
    <R2/>
    <R2/>
    <R2>
       <R3/>
       <R3/>
       <R3/>
    </R2>
  </R1>
  <R1/>
  <R1>
    <R2/>
    <R2/>
  </R1>
  <R1/>
</body>
```

Basically these R1 - R3 elements signify sect-1, sect-2, sect-3 type elements. R2's are nested within their previous sibling R1 and R3's are nested within their previous sibling R2. Elements that are the same are on the same level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for-each-group group-starting-with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="prefix" as="xs:string" select="'R'"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
  <xsl:param name="elements" as="element()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$elements" group-starting-with="*[local-name() = concat($prefix, $level)]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., $level + 1)"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="body">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(*, 1)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```