# Creating structured documents using nested XSLT2 grouping

Tags: html, xslt-2.0

I have (well-formed) HTML files of the form:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <h1>h1.1</h1>
    <p>p1.1</p>
    <p>p1.2</p>
    <h2>h2.1.1</h2>
    <p>p2.1.1</p>
    <p>p2.1.2</p>
    <h2>h2.2</h2>
    <p>p2.1.2a</p>
    <p>p2.1.2b</p>
    <h1>h1.2</h1>
    <p>p1.2a</p>
    <p>p1.2b</p>
    <h2>2.1</h2>
    <p>p2.2.1a</p>
    <p>p2.2.2b</p>
</body>
```

and wish to create structured HTML where the h1 and h2 represent different levels of nesting - something like

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <div class="h1">
        <h1>h1.1</h1>
        <p>p1.1</p>
        <p>p1.2</p>
        <div class="h2">
            <h2>h2.1.1</h2>
            <p>p2.1.1</p>
            <p>p2.1.2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="h2">
            <h2>h2.2</h2>
            <p>p2.1.2a</p>
            <p>p2.1.2b</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="h1">
        <h1>h1.2</h1>
        <p>p1.2a</p>
        <p>p1.2b</p>
        <div class="h2">
            <h2>2.1</h2>
            <p>p2.2.1a</p>
            <p>p2.2.2b</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

There is no regularity in the documents other than containing h1 and h2. I can nest the h1 elements using XSLT2 grouping, but wish to group 2 (or even more) levels of h1/h2/h3. I can do this with multiple passes of a transformer (i.e. re-running Saxon with separate grouping for h1 and h2) but would prefer to do it in a single pass if possible. My current experiment (showing I have been trying) is:

```
  <xsl:template match="h:body">
<h:div class="xml-content" >
  <xsl:for-each-group select="h:*" group-starting-with="h:h1">
     <!-- h:div needs to go here? -->
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[not(self::h:h1)]">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="self::h:*" group-starting-with="h:h2">
     <!-- h:div needs to go here? -->
              <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:for-each> 
            </hb>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
          </ha>
      </xsl:for-each> 
    </h:section>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</h:div>
```

but this only groups the h1 and h2 and not the following elements. How can I do this?

Comment: Your XSLT creates elements like `section` or `ha` and `hb` which don't appear in your wanted output so it is a bit difficult to suggest changes. Try to make those samples consistent. In general you simply need to write a `for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h2"` inside the outer `for-each-group` and of course the wrapper element `section` or `div` you want to use, a nested `for-each` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks. So I should use nested `xsl:for-each-group, but not nested `xsl:for-each. I assume from you reply that you think it is possible to do this.. (The ha and hb were diagnostics and I'll remove them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either write a recursive function doing the grouping for each level or nest the for-each-group elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
      <div class="h1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h2">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::h2">
              <div class="h2">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </div>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output with that is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

   <body>
      <div class="h1">
         <h1>h1.1</h1>
         <p>p1.1</p>
         <p>p1.2</p>
         <div class="h2">
            <h2>h2.1.1</h2>
            <p>p2.1.1</p>
            <p>p2.1.2</p>
         </div>
         <div class="h2">
            <h2>h2.2</h2>
            <p>p2.1.2a</p>
            <p>p2.1.2b</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="h1">
         <h1>h1.2</h1>
         <p>p1.2a</p>
         <p>p1.2b</p>
         <div class="h2">
            <h2>2.1</h2>
            <p>p2.2.1a</p>
            <p>p2.2.2b</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: As for recursion, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406846/nesting-flat-xml-siblings/27407470#27407470 for a similar question and a similar answer using a recursive function.